# `re.search` is not giving entire match (Python)

Tags: python

Below is one line of my file "test.txt":

```
"","links":{"self":"https://1.1.1.10/abc/abc_config/v1/domain/1234-e0f2-11e3-8169-dfgd1234/devices/devicerecords/71a54444-442e-11e7-b2e0-ef8622226aec"},"name":"10.105.206.87"},{"id":"118e8d36-49ba-11e7-8c4e-fb1fe31bd90c","type":"
```

I want to fetch `("name":"10.105.206.87"},{"id":"118e8d36-49ba-11e7-8c4e-fb1fe31bd90c","type")` portion from the line below is my code-

```
 f=open("test.txt","r")
 str1=f.read()
 str2=str1.split("Device")
 for string in str2:
    if "name" in string:
       reg='\"name.+,\"typ'
       match=re.search(reg,string)
       print (match)
```

it  matches half of the expected output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(164, 237), match='"name":"10.105.206.87"},{"id":"118e8d36-49ba-11e7>
```

I want to print entire string:

```
 "name":"10.105.206.87"},{"id":"118e8d36-49ba-11e7-8c4e-fb1fe31bd90c","type"
```

Let me know, if I am passing the wrong regex.

Comment: Looks like JSON.  Try the `json` module instead.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is correct. You are trying to print the result of re.search. Try to pull only the matched text like below.

```
 reg='\"name.+,\"type\"'
 match=re.search(reg,string)
 print (match.group())
```

BTW, I have modified the pattern a little to match till `"type"`